# Invoke Command Computer Name not valid error when passing from variable

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I running some test on Invoke Command and found some interesting result.

**This is the success code snippet.**

```
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName serverA,serverB,serverC,serverD,serverE -ScriptBlock{Get-WindowsUpdate | Format-Table -AutoSize}
```

**This is the code snippet which return error.**

```
$servers="serverA,serverB,serverC,serverD,serverE"
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock{Get-WindowsUpdate | Format-Table -AutoSize}
```

Error Message:

> Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are
>   trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI
>   objects instead of strings.

Why there is an error occur when read from variables? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter `Computers` accepts collection of strings. The comma is regarded as a separator, to build a collection. Using it as: `$servers="serverA,serverB,serverC,serverD,serverE"` is one large string, containing commas, not a collection of strings.

It should be: `$servers="serverA","serverB","serverC","serverD","serverE"`